# How to deal with the peptide sequences that have atypical amino acids in the seuqnces?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fingerprint, rdkit, cheminformatics

I am not a bioinformatician and my question may sound basic.

I have some issues with RDKit
**The issue:** there are some sequences that have X in the antimicrobial peptide sequence.  Seems that RDKit cannot process these cases. For example the following sequences:
`seq = 'HFXGTLVNLAKKIL', 'HFLGXLVNLAKKIL', 'HFLGTLVNXAKKIL', 'fPVXLfPXXL', 'SRWPSPGRPRPFPGRPKPIFRPRPXNXYAPPXPXDRW'...]`, and the `Chem.MolFromSequence(seq[i])` returns None for these cases.

My question is how do deal with this kind of sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain the reason for the output of `None`

As you can see in this [list of abbreviations](https://www.genome.jp/kegg/catalog/codes1.html) for peptide sequences the letter "X" stands for "unknown". Basically the *real* amino acid could not be discovered there. Therefore RDKit can not create a mol object of your data, because parts of it are unknown.

> RETURNS:
>
> ```
> a Mol object, None on failure.
> ```

[Source of quote above](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.html#rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.MolFromSequence)

Since RDKit's managing of this case is logically reasonable you have to answer your question yourself: "How do I deal with unknown amino acids?". You need a preprocessing of those sequences and maybe replace the "X" with something else, or delete that sequence entirely from your dataframe. But this depends on your own usecase.